# Interface Font relative path in userprefs

Tags: interface, customization, path, font

I've currently put my Blender Preferences under Version Control in order to share these between my various Windows and Linux OSes, and is working pretty fine, at the exception of interface fonts.

As I use a custom font for my UI (Roboto), I need to reference a OTF file that is in a sibling folder of the blender preferences (next to the 2.91, 2.92, 2.93...)

```
- ./
- ../
- 2.91/
- 2.92/
- fonts/
```

However, I can't seem to be able to define a relative path in my blender preferences (Preferences/Interface/Text Rendering/Interface Font). The path is stored as absolute path and seem to ignore the relative_path option of the window.

Is there a way to define it manually to make it work? Am I missing something in the fonts workflow?

(I've checked [this page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html), however inputting manually `./config/../Fonts/myfont.otf` etc doesnt seem to work)